# How to avoid audio track skipping audio buffer in android?

Tags: android, mp3, audio-streaming, aac

I want to implement live audio streaming for my Android application.So I used `OpenCORE aacdec` library and wrapped it.Because I have to play both MP3 and AAC.

Saved the stream as files (having size 50 * 1024), read and decode each file using library's `BufferReader` and `Decoder`.

For reading each file, modified the `next()` method of `BufferReader`.Inside the `next()` read file as a buffer having size same as file size(i.e,50*1024). Writing these decodes buffer in to `AudioTrack` in a thread and play it.

```
public void run() {
           short[] samplesBuffered = getDecodedSample(filePath);

        if (samplesBuffered != null) {
            // samples written to AudioTrack in this round:
            int writtenNow = 0;
            int ln = samplesBuffered.length;
            do {
                if (writtenNow != 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                int written = track.write(samplesBuffered, writtenNow, ln);
                if (written < 0) {
                    stopped = true;
                    break;
                }
                writtenTotal += written;
                int buffered = writtenTotal - track.getPlaybackHeadPosition()
                        * configuration.getChannels();
                if (!stopped && !isPlaying) {
                    if (buffered * 2 >= configuration.getBufferSizeInBytes()) {
                        track.play();
                        isPlaying = true;
                    }
                }

                writtenNow += written;
                ln -= written;
            } while (ln > 0 && !stopped);
        }
    }


private  synchronized short[] getDecodedSample(String filePath) {
        InputStream iStream = null;
        BufferReader reader = null;
        try {
            if (decoder != null) {
                decoder.stop();
            }
            iStream = new FileInputStream(filePath.trim());
            reader = new BufferReader(PlayerUtils.computeInputBufferSize(declaredBitRate, decodeBufferCapacityMs), iStream);
            //new Thread(reader).start();

            Decoder.Info info = decoder.start(reader);
            short[] decodeBuffer = new short[PCMFeed.msToSamples( decodeBufferCapacityMs, info.getSampleRate(), info.getChannels())];

            info = decoder.decode(decodeBuffer, decodeBuffer.length);

            int nsamp = info.getRoundSamples();
            if (nsamp == 0 || reader.isStopped()){
                return null;
            }

            return decodeBuffer;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                iStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

decodeBufferCapacityMs : 5000
 audioBufferCapacityMs  : 1000
 audio track buffer size : 88200 
 sample rate             : 22050

My problem is that the AudioTrack skips the last part of each buffer.How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this was a year ago, but in case you're still seeking a solution, or others need it - You need to play out the whole buffer you need to write to a 'track' whatever it is left in your PCMFeed buffer, and not imeddiatelly finish after your `do-while (ln > 0 && !stopped);` loop.

Please check more details here: https://github.com/vbartacek/aacdecoder-android/blob/master/decoder/src/com/spoledge/aacdecoder/PCMFeed.java

And pay attention to `waitForLastTone` method and logic around it.